# Как организовать MVC для статических страниц PHP

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, view

Друзья помогите с вопросом. Есть задача нужно использовать паттерн MVC для создания статической страницы.Нет никаких баз данных но есть обычные шаблоны (`HTML , CSS ,JAVASCRIPT`).Как можно реализовать такой подход.

Для реализация  я какие то шаги предпринял .Создал класс  Router  , создал  функцию для обработки  роутов  подключил конроллер но  после  этого  незнаю как реализовать  view  без 
model.

Вот код

```
Файл .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Файл index.php 

require("router.php");

$router = new Router;
$router->add();

Файл router.php



class Router
{   
    // Роуты  для страниц
    private $router = array(

     "about" => "about/index",
     "service" => "service/index",
     "portfolio" => "portfolio/index",
     "contact" => "contact/index"
    );

    private $url;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->router;
    }

    public function add()
    {
        if (!empty($_GET['url'])) 
        {
            $this->url = trim($_GET['url'], "/");

            foreach ($this->router as $key => $value) 
            {      
                    // Совпдение роутов
                if (preg_match("~$key~", $this->url)) 
                {
                    $segment = explode("/", $value);
                     // PSR  стандарт
                    $controllerName = ucfirst(array_shift($segment))."Controller";

                    $actionName = "action".ucfirst(array_shift($segment));

                    $controllerFile = "controller/" . $controllerName . ".php";

                    if (file_exists($controllerFile)) 
                    {
                        require_once($controllerFile);
                    }

                    $controllerobject = new $controllerName;
                    $controllerobject->$actionName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите разобратся остальным кодом заранее спасибо .

Comment: какой-то странный вопрос. Вы хоть один пример реализации контроллера видели? Обычно контроллер вызывает вью, передавая данные, которые получил из модели. Если нету данныхт и модели, значит нет и кода для низ. Но в остальном какая проблема вызвать из контроллера вью?

Comment: А что можно реализовать  в модели для статической страницы ?

Comment: зачем писать свой велосипед? это уже давно реализовано в любом фреймфорке, если вам интересно для начала посмотрите как это всё работает в lavarel/yii и попробуйте разобраться

Comment: вы пробуете следовать mvc, когда даже не понимаете, что это, какие ответственности должны быть у классов, какую роль играет ваш роутинг в вашем примере? что он делает - всё сразу?

Comment: ничего не надо писать в модели вообще ничего. статический сайт лучше всего писать на чистом HTML, но если так очень хочется извратиться, то будет толкьо VC, без M

Comment: А какая литература есть по MVC  .Не фреймворки?

Comment: можете сделать `StaticController` с методом `viewPage` а в качестве модели будет имя отображаемого статического файла.

Answer (score 0):

```
Файл .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Файл index.php 

require("router.php");

$router = new Router;
$router->add();

Файл router.php



class Router
{   
    // Роуты  для страниц
    private $router = array(

     "about" => "about/index",
     "service" => "service/index",
     "portfolio" => "portfolio/index",
     "contact" => "contact/index"
    );

    private $url;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->router;
    }

    public function add()
    {
        if (!empty($_GET['url'])) 
        {
            $this->url = trim($_GET['url'], "/");

            foreach ($this->router as $key => $value) 
            {      
                    // Совпдение роутов
                if (preg_match("~$key~", $this->url)) 
                {
                    $segment = explode("/", $value);
                     // PSR  стандарт
                    $controllerName = ucfirst(array_shift($segment))."Controller";

                    $actionName = "action".ucfirst(array_shift($segment));

                    $controllerFile = "controller/" . $controllerName . ".php";

                    if (file_exists($controllerFile)) 
                    {
                        require_once($controllerFile);
                    }

                    $controllerobject = new $controllerName;
                    $controllerobject->$actionName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Кантролерр `AboutController` и метод  `actionIndex`

```
class AboutController
{
   public function actionIndex()
   {
      include("view/about.html");
      return true;
   }
}
```